# Rails routes: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, subdomain

This is my first attempt to use subdomain inside Rails project. I plan to have routes like:

1. example.com/about-us (static page)
2. example.com/contact-us (static page)
3. app.example.com
4. app.example.com/orders

I have this inside my **routes.rb** file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    constraints :subdomain => "app" do
        resources :orders
    end

  root "orders#index"
end
```

And this is the result of my rake routes:

```
Prefix     Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
    orders GET    /orders(.:format)          orders#index {:subdomain=>"app"}
           POST   /orders(.:format)          orders#create {:subdomain=>"app"}
 new_order GET    /orders/new(.:format)      orders#new {:subdomain=>"app"}
edit_order GET    /orders/:id/edit(.:format) orders#edit {:subdomain=>"app"}
     order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)      orders#show {:subdomain=>"app"}
           PATCH  /orders/:id(.:format)      orders#update {:subdomain=>"app"}
           PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)      orders#update {:subdomain=>"app"}
           DELETE /orders/:id(.:format)      orders#destroy {:subdomain=>"app"}
      root GET    /                          orders#index
```

When I try to access http://app.rails_subdomain.dev/orders/, I get this error:

[image]

And when I try to access http://app.rails_subdomain.dev/orders/1, I get this error:

[image]

What I'm missing here? What does `wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)` error means here?

**Note 1**: before I create the routes file, I already run `rails g scaffold orders name` and already run `rake db:migrate`.

**Note 2**: I'm using [Pow](http://pow.cx/manual.html).

Comment: Please post your Orders controller info as well for Edit/Show actions. Whats your Rails version? Error says you are passing 3 arguments instead of 1, that probably means your `order` and `@order` objects are incorrect and might be Array or something. Can you check in database/console what your Order in database looks like? Also i suggest putting `binding.pry` or `byebug` etc before this `order` is rendered and check what Data this variable contains..

Comment: Ditto - you need to provide code for how you're defining `@order`.